# Integrating application with Sugar CRM using java and oauth2

Tags: java, sugarcrm

I'm trying to integrating sugar CRM in my application using Java & Oauth2 to retrieve the contacts from the Sugar CRM.
For that one, I need to register as a developer and need to register my application in their portal to get client_id and client_secret values.

I have gone through the sugar CRM developer website but unable to find the useful info.

Can anyone provide some guidelines for registering as a developer and to get 
client_id and client_secret values for my application.

Also in the documentation they given The base endpoint for the REST service can be found at `http://<site_url>/rest/v{version}/`
But I couldn't find the value of `<site_url>`. Can anyone suggest me the value of `<site_url>`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.9/Integration/Web_Services/v10/Endpoints/oauth2token_POST/

See, there is a `/oauth2/token` POST endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have navigated to the replied URL but how can I get the client id, client secret values for my application is my question.